# Text on data structures to use along with Lipschutz

Tags: data-structures, reference-request, books

I will be teaching a data structures course this Fall semester for second year computer science undergraduates. The textbook and syllabus currently used follow the text "Schaum's outlines: Data structures with C" by Lipschutz.   I think the Schaum's outlines series are more a supplement to textbooks and that the students should be given another standard textbook as a reference which we can follow closely.  Which text would be good to use?   The text should be at the same beginner's level as Lipschutz's text.  Faculty who are teaching other sections of the course will be using Lipschutz, and all students will be taking a common exam, so I can't avoid Lipschutz entirely.

I prefer the classic Data Structures and Algorithms book by Aho, Hocroft and Ullman.  But I was thinking a modern reference with C implementation and at a slightly more elementary level might be easier for the students to follow.  The students will also be taking a data structures lab course in parallel where they will have to do C implementation.

I found Weiss' "Data structures and Algorithm Analysis in C" online.  Would that be a good text to follow?

Comment: We generally frown on questions that are solely or primarily based on opinions, as those basically turn into opinion polls, and our site's format is not well-suited for that (see our [help/dont-ask]).  Can you edit the question to specify objective requirements/criteria for evaluating the book, and list why you've rejected the ones you mention?

Comment: If you're talking about [this book](https://archive.org/details/DataStructuresWithCBySchaumLipschutz), then I'm really sorry for you. I've just opened the book in some two or three random pages. Besides seeing "void main()", which already is annoying, I saw a return of a pointer to auto storage as a means to implement a substring routine. Maybe the author know much about data structures, but he surely seems to be lacking on extremely basic C programming skills. Using this book seems like a bad idea. Besides, it's from 2011, but for sure that doesn't reflect the C style in it.

Comment: @D.W. I haven't rejected any books so far.  It's just that books in the Schaum's outline series generally have problems and solutions and not as much motivation of the material as good texts.  Schaum's books are meant to be supplements for texts and intended for exam study rather than stand-alone texts.   As for objective criteria, I'm not sure myself - I'm just looking for an excellent text (like Aho et al's) but which might be easier for the students to follow and with C programs to help out the students more.

Comment: @D.W. Feel free to mention texts you have gone through or heard of.  I don't have any particular objective requirements/criteria in mind - perhaps people can mention these themselves.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueA.Oliveira  I can't access the book through your link. But yes, I believe it's the same book.

Comment: Btw, I have went through Data Structures and Algorithms book by Aho, Hocroft and Ullman (the one you mentioned) a while ago and I enjoyed it quite a lot. Have you taken a look at Sedgewick's algorithms (which includes DS stuff too) using C? I've heard good things about them.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueA.Oliveira Thanks for pointing out Sedgewick. I didn't know it had C.

Comment: `I can't access the book through your link` - try again, and take a close look at the "DOWNLOAD OPTIONS" box (on the right in my browser window): I'd guess [PDF WITH TEXT](https://archive.org/download/DataStructuresWithCBySchaumLipschutz/Data%20Structures%20With%20C%20-%20by%20schaum%20lipschutz_text.pdf) to be a promising link.